# elegantbook could I remove the "author" from the cover?

Tags: pdftex

The book cover will display author name with "author".
I simply want the name. How could I remove the "author"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Put `\renewcommand{\authorname}{} `  before `\begin{document}`